Issues on a MacBook Air 2020 T2 w/Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu on my MacBook, but my native keyboard and touchpad aren't working and I am stumped as to what to do to make them work. I don't want to install T2 Linux unless it is the only option. I am sorry if I didn't include any vital information in this text, please ask and I will give.
External keyboards and mice work fine, I see no error messages, and I believe this to be a driver issue. I tried installing apple-bce-drv from T2 linux into my drivers but that did not work.
I tried giving the apple-bce-drv permissions since that fixed another driver issue I had with my Wi-Fi card but that did not work either. I have checked other questions but none give me an answer that works.

Hello everyone, I did some further research into this issue and found that there were no solutions and those who did have this same problem just gave up, so I decided to install T2 Ubuntu from https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu, credit to Aditya Garg and others for making this, it works just like normal Ubuntu and I would recommend just erasing the partition, making a new one and using this. Saved me a lot of time and only took 30ish minutes to set up.

I’m voting to close this question because OP has installed a different OS custom designed for the hardware. The issue no longer exists.
